# Regex - lowercase alphanumeric and forward slash

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression that allows lowercase alphanumeric characters, however now I need to add a forward slash.

My current regex is `^[a-z0-9]+$`.

I've tried `^[a-z0-9\/]+$` but it's not working.

Comment: What is the code and what string did you try? It should work. It must be `var pat = "^[a-z0-9/]+$"`

Comment: No need for a verbatim string literal, Avinash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var pat = "^[a-z0-9/]+$";
```

No need to escape the `/` in C# patterns.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/8NYOVX):

```
var pat = "^[a-z0-9/]+$";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch("abc122/", pat)); // TRUE
```

Comment: Note that a verbatim string literal `var pat = @"^[a-z0-9/]+$";` will also work. And `var pat = @"^[a-z0-9\/]+$";` should work too, because in the verbatim string literals, ``\`` won't create an escape sequence.